# Admin Dashboard with Custom Tab for Client

Tags: plugins, widgets, admin, metabox, add-menu-page

I am trying to create a basic Tour Date widget.

When the user clicks on the Tour Date Tab from the admin dashboard I want them to be presented with five fields.

1. Date
2. Venue
3. City, State or Country
4. Ticket Link
5. Share Link

I've figured out how to add a custom tab after experimenting with ACF and CMB2 only to realize that the Wordpress codex does indeed explain the basic process here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

but not knowing that it was called an "administration menu" and searches for Dashboard Tab, Admin Tab, Admin Menu in Google yielded surprisingly confusing results. ;) I am up to Step three and while I was successfully able to create these fields with ACF and linking that to a custom post type(see below) I don't know how to have the same info appear in this new Administrative menu page(Tour) that I've made.

```
<?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. This builds the menu in the admin area */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Tour Dates', 'Tour', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options', 'dashicons-book', 6 );
}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

and the code I was able to link up to ACF in order to do this two levels down within the Post option:

// Register Custom Post Type
     function custom_post_type() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Tour Dates', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Tour', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Tour', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Tour dates and upcoming shows', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'tourdate', 'category' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-post-status',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => false,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'tour', $args );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```